Conditional number formatting based on checkbox
It's been a while since I've used excel and my skills are a bit rusty. I'm working on a spreadsheet to keep track of my walks. I've got a checkbox to switch between "Miles" and "Steps."
Depending on what units I'm using, I'd like to format the cells differently. If steps I'd like to eliminate the decimals. For miles, I want 2 decimal places even if the second one is 0. I.e. 3.80 or 3.00. I haven't decided yet about just hiding 0 values altogether.

You may select the values cells > Conditional Formatting > Use a formula to determine which cells to format > Enter following formulas:
=IF($A1="Miles",1,0) --- Click Format > Number, set 2 decimals.
=IF($A1="Steps",1,0) --- Click Format > Number, set no decimals.


you don't need to construct an IF() statement. You can just put $A1="Miles" in the condition box of the CF dialog. You can use any expression that evaluates to True or False.

True / False statements may need a surrounding pair of ( and ) though, at times you get an auto-insertion of "'s around what you wrote as formula.
